# Hiding the R code in Rmarkdown/knit and just showing the results

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In my R Markdown documents, I sometimes want to just generate a report without showing the actual code (specially when I send it to my boss). How can I hide the R code and just show the graph and results?

For example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r fig.width=16, fig.height=6}
plot(cars)
```
````

This shows both the commands and the plot. How can I remove the commands from my HTML report?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Sure, just do

````
```{r someVar, echo=FALSE}
someVariable
```
````

to show some (previously computed) variable `someVariable`.  Or run code that prints etc pp.

So for plotting, I have eg

````
### Impact of choice of ....
```{r somePlot, echo=FALSE}
plotResults(Res, Grid, "some text", "some more text")
```
````

where the plotting function `plotResults` is from a local package.

Comment: or put `opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)` in a code chunk at the head of your document to set this globally

Comment: Make sure not to echo the opts_chunk command!  Putting  `{r echo=FALSE} opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)` at the top of the doc (in a code chunk) should solve everything

Answer (score 57):

Might also be interesting for you to know that you can use:

```
{r echo=FALSE, results='hide',message=FALSE}
a<-as.numeric(rnorm(100))
hist(a, breaks=24)
```

to exclude all the commands you give, all the results it spits out and all message info being spit out by R (eg. after library(ggplot) or something)

Comment: That is nice, `results='hide'`  represses text output, but shows plots!

Answer (score 54):

Just aggregating the answers and expanding on the basics. Here are three options:

### 1) Hide Code (individual chunk)

We can include `echo=FALSE` in the chunk header:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

### 2) Hide Chunks (globally).

We can change the default behaviour of **knitr** using the `knitr::opts_chunk$set` function. We call this at the start of the document and include `include=FALSE` in the chunk header to suppress any output:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

### 3) Collapsed Code Chunks

For HTML outputs, we can use code folding to hide the code in the output file. It will still include the code but can only be seen once a user clicks on this. You can read about this further [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#code-folding).

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: "hide"
---


```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Can I exclude printing code when knitting to PDF using an option in the preamble? `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)` works, but I would prefer an option like `pdf_document code_folding: "hide"`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also parse a **standard markdown document** (without code blocks *per se*) on the fly by the [**markdownreports package**](https://markdownreports.github.io/).