# rmarkdown: toggling code blocks in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I'm producing an RMarkdown document with knitr, and I'd like to give my readers the option to show/hide code blocks.

I assume that this will involve adding some JavaScript (e.g. `toggle_visibility`), but I'm not sure how to add it to a knitr document.  Would I add it to the CSS somehow?  Or return something with `asis = TRUE` and put the JavaScript there, as in [this example](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/javascript/)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide code in RMarkdown, with option to see it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127321/how-to-hide-code-in-rmarkdown-with-option-to-see-it)

Comment: Thanks, my search terms weren't leading me there when I searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can include additional content](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#advanced-customization) in the HTML header, before body, or after body for HTML output from R Markdown documents. I have a simple JavaScript function [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/misc/toggleR.js), and you may include it in `<script></script>`. The [**knitrBootstrap**](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=knitrBootstrap) package is much fancier than my naive JS function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Yihui's answer and the one @Shaun Jackman referenced in a comment, someone also pointed me to this example:

- [code](https://github.com/sjackman/abyss-activity/blob/master/index-header.html)
- [rendered](https://sjackman.github.io/abyss-activity/): search for `[show answer]`).

Edited to add a [minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/scx4hdwy/).  Note that this example requires jquery.

Comment: That someone was also me. =)