# Is it possible to hide in external and in R generated plots/pictures like code in html documents generated with knitr?

Tags: r, image, markdown, knitr, show-hide

Is it possible to hide in R generated plots as well as external pictures as it is possible with source code when I preparing html slides with knitr? I made different Venn diagrams on an external site and some network plots... and I made a lot of them. To not have to see everything whenever I open the html (but still to be able to have a fast overlook) I would like to have them hiden like a code which generates some results....

This is the header of my Rmd R-Knitr-Document:

```
---
title: "Analysis_WP1 16S+ITS"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    highlight: textmate
    code_folding: hide
---
```

This is working:

````
<img src="myimage"/>
```{r}
variable_with_network_plot
```
````

but this not (as it is no R-code... so far I understood it...)

````
```{r}
<img src="myimage"/>
variable_with_network_plot
```
````

Do you have any I idea how I could get it managed? It is just for saving a lot of space... a faster overlook over the data (and still have everything in one document) and at last: to be able to print out what is needed a bit easier.

Cheers,
TheGreenOne

Comment: what is `variable_with_network_plot`?

Comment: It should just be an example variable I generated in R like `variable_with_network_plot<- make_network(input, distance="any_distance", ...)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want a toggle button to hide things [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972149/r-markdown-pdf-temporarily-hide-spoiler-code-for-quiz-takers)? or you want to have a chunk with html code that you can set to eval=FALSE and not show?

Comment: I would like to have something like this hide/show button for external graphics and R graphics.