# toggle show/hide code in RMarkdown

Tags: javascript, knitr, r-markdown

I am generating an HTML report using Rmarkdown in which I want the user to have an option of looking at code (when they want by using a toggle show/hide code) before each section or figure.

I am wondering if there is an option to do so globally and individually for each code chunk.

I have looked at some previous solutions using javascript, but I am not familiar with the language. I was hoping there is an option I can choose within Rmarkdown.

Previous approaches using javascript are shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/d37E0mP3w6k) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127321/how-to-hide-code-in-rmarkdown-with-option-to-see-it), but I am not sure how to include these in my Rmarkdown file. I have tried the following, but it didn't work

````
<script src="toggleR.js"></script> 
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

A working example in Rmarkdown would be extremely helpful!!

Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer for your second link should give you what you want. For output chunks take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/toggle-visibility-of-fold-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents/37839683#37839683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide code in RMarkdown, with option to see it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127321/how-to-hide-code-in-rmarkdown-with-option-to-see-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer to a similar question by Yihue -this functionality has now been added as code folding. See more at 
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html