# How to add code folding to output chunks in rmarkdown html documents

Tags: r, r-markdown

I really appreciate the "code_folding" feature in RMarkdown. However, what I really need is to have the code show all the time and toggle the display on the output.

````
---
title: "test file"
author: "dayne"
date: "June 10, 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is a basic example.

```{r}
3 + 4
```
````

Is there a way to toggle the output rather than the code? The best (but not ideal) solution I have thought of is to add `collapse=TRUE` to the chunks, but then the code and the output still display at the same time.

Link to the compiled document: http://rpubs.com/daynefiler/188408

Comment: I just realize my english is so poor by finding out what *toggle the display on the output* means.

Comment: @Psidom I have added a link to the compiled document demonstrating the "code folding." Notice how you can click on the "code" button and the code appears/disappears. I would like the same functionality with the output rather than the code.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**TOC:**

1. Full control over which chunks should be folded
2. Fold all chunks that contain more than one line of code/output

---

### 1. Full control over which chunks should be folded

I wanted to have the same functionality as well and did the following:

I created a JavaScript that looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $chunks = $('.fold');

  $chunks.each(function () {

    // add button to source code chunks
    if ( $(this).hasClass('s') ) {
      $('pre.r', this).prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Source</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre.r', this).children('code').attr('class', 'folded');
    }

    // add button to output chunks
    if ( $(this).hasClass('o') ) {
      $('pre:not(.r)', this).has('code').prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Output</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre:not(.r)', this).children('code:not(r)').addClass('folded');

      // add button to plots
      $(this).find('img').wrap('<pre class=\"plot\"></pre>');
      $('pre.plot', this).prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Plot</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre.plot', this).children('img').addClass('folded');

    }
  });

  // hide all chunks when document is loaded
  $('.folded').css('display', 'none')

  // function to toggle the visibility
  $('.showopt').click(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    if (label.indexOf("Show") >= 0) {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Show", "Hide"));
    } else {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Hide", "Show"));
    }
    $(this).siblings('code, img').slideToggle('fast', 'swing');
  });
});
```

Since I am no JS crack it might not be perfect, but it does what it is supposed to. 
Include it in your Rmd file:

```
<script src="js/hideOutput.js"></script>
```

I also wrote some CSS definitions to style the button:

```
.showopt {
  background-color: #004c93;
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  float: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.showopt:hover {
    background-color: #dfe4f2;
    color: #004c93;
}

pre.plot {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

After including both, the JS file and the stylesheet, you can hide chunks by wrapping a div container around them with one of the following classes:

**Hide output only**

````
<div class="fold o">
```{r}
  ...
```
</div>
````

**Hide source code**

````
<div class="fold s">
```{r}
  ...
```
</div>
````

**Hide both**

````
<div class="fold s o">
```{r}
  ...
```
</div>
````

The script detects the type of each chunk (e.g. source code, text output or plot output) and labels the buttons accordingly.

The result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

---

### 2. Fold all chunks that contain more than one line of code/output

Here is a version of the script that adds the folding feature to all chunks that are longer than one line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $plots = $('img.plot');
  $chunks = $('pre').has('code');
  $chunks = $chunks.filter(function(idx) {
    return $(this).children('code').outerHeight(false) > parseInt($(this).css('line-height'));
  });

  $chunks.each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('r')) {
      $(this).append("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Source</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
    } else {
      $(this).append("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Output</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
    }
  });

  $plots.each(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<pre class=\"plot\"></pre>');
    $(this).parent('pre.plot').prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Plot</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
  });

  // hide all chunks when document is loaded
  $chunks.children('code').toggle();
  $('pre.plot').children('img').toggle();
  // function to toggle the visibility
  $('.showopt').click(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    if (label.indexOf("Show") >= 0) {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Show", "Hide"));
    } else {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Hide", "Show"));
    }
    $(this).siblings('code, img').slideToggle('fast', 'swing');
  });
});
```

Just include it with `<script src="js/hideAll.js"></script>` and you don't need to wrap div containers around your code chunks.
One thing you have to add in your Rmd document though is the following global chunk option:

````
```{r, echo = F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.extra = 'class="plot"')
```
````

It is needed to identify graphical output.

Comment: Really outstanding answer. Thanks!

Comment: side note: see [this page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#custom_css) for embedding custom CSS in your R Markdown.

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter, any ideas on how to use this CSS without losing the default syntax highlighting in the output code chunks? I think R Markdown has a default CSS file somewhere in its system folder, maybe it would be possible to integrate the two?

Comment: Instead of specifying the div like `<div class="fold o">`, can it be included in the chunk options like `{r,fold_source=TRUE,fold_output=TRUE}`?

Comment: Not with the above code. I will review my code this week and see what has changed in `knitr` since I wrote it.

Answer (score 29):

How about this lo-fi solution?

````
<details><summary>Click here</summary>
Some text

```{r code}
# even code
print("Hello world!")
```
</details>
````

Not mine, but I like it.

Comment: very nice--no js or css required

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to modify this so the arrow is on a section header to fold sections? I tried this: <details>
<summary>
# section 2
</summary>
Here are the details.
</details>

But it creates the arrow above the section header.

Comment: is there a way to specify that the default is open, as opposed to closed as it is this way?

Comment: <details open> worked for me to set the default to open

Comment: seems adding header inside <details> cause texts after that to lose all formatting.  `### Step 1

```{r}
print("hello")
```

<details>
<summary>Click here</summary>
#### Step 1-1
```{r}
print("hello")
```

</details>

### Step 2

```{r}
print("hello")
```
everything starting ### Step 2 breaks apart. Is there solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

A quick an hacky way to toggle a section (not necessarily code):

Enclose the sections to toggle with `<div class="toggle"><button>TOGGLE_TEXT</button>` and `<\div>` in your .Rmd file

````
1. How many users are in the second, but not the first, user table?

    <div class="toggle"><button>Solution</button>
    ```{r}
    setdiff(user2, user) %>% nrow()
    ```
    </div>
````

Put this at the bottom of the .Rmd file (or ideally in a .js file linked to all your pages).

```
<script>
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
</script>
```

Put this in your .css file (you'll have to play with the height for your button).

```
.toggle {
  height: 1.55em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.toggle.open {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Since bootstrap is already loaded, using `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Show session info</button>` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I straight up copied the javascript from the source of another Rmarkdown document where I set [`code_folding: show`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#code_folding). I saved the javascript as `py_code_folding.js` and added `<script src="py_code_folding.js"></script>` to the top of my Rmarkdown document. The only limitation is that I had to hardcode in my javascript whether I want the blocks to be initially shown or hidden.

```
window.initializePythonCodeFolding = function(show) {

  // handlers for show-all and hide all
  $("#rmd-show-all-code").click(function() {
    $('div.r-code-collapse').each(function() {
      $(this).collapse('show');
    });
  });
  $("#rmd-hide-all-code").click(function() {
    $('div.r-code-collapse').each(function() {
      $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
  });

  // index for unique code element ids
  var currentIndex = 10000;

  // select all R code blocks
  var rCodeBlocks = $('pre.python');
  rCodeBlocks.each(function() {

    // create a collapsable div to wrap the code in
    var div = $('<div class="collapse r-code-collapse"></div>');
    if (show)
      div.addClass('in');
    var id = 'rcode-643E0F36' + currentIndex++;
    div.attr('id', id);
    $(this).before(div);
    $(this).detach().appendTo(div);

    // add a show code button right above
    var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (show ? 'Hide' : 'Code') + '</span>');
    var showCodeButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs code-folding-btn pull-right"></button>');
    showCodeButton.append(showCodeText);
    showCodeButton
        .attr('data-toggle', 'collapse')
        .attr('data-target', '#' + id)
        .attr('aria-expanded', show)
        .attr('aria-controls', id);

    var buttonRow = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    var buttonCol = $('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');

    buttonCol.append(showCodeButton);
    buttonRow.append(buttonCol);

    div.before(buttonRow);

    // update state of button on show/hide
    div.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
      showCodeText.text('Code');
    });
    div.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      showCodeText.text('Hide');
    });
  });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
  window.initializePythonCodeFolding("show" === "show");
});
```