# Default code folding by individual chunk in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am writing up a lesson in HTML using rmarkdown to demonstrate how to implement analytic methods in R, and because of this the document has a lot of code that is needed to understand those methods, but also a lot of code that is used only for generating plots and figures. I would like to show the first sort of code by default, and leave the plotting code available for students to view but hidden by default.

I know that rmarkdown has recently added support for code folding by setting the `code_folding` html_document argument to either `show` or `hide`. However, this either leaves all code chunks unfolded or folded by default -- is there any way to indicate whether **individual** code chunks should be shown or folded by default while allowing code folding?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents/37839683#37839683   It allows to specifically fold single chunks (outputs, source or both)

Comment: If you're looking for a simple workaround, you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53870441/3430463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code folding for individual chunks in R Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543431/code-folding-for-individual-chunks-in-r-markdown)

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here wondering the same thing. This is a not a perfect solution, but I write the code twice: once in regular markdown (so it displays - note no `{r}` after the three backticks), and another time in a code chunk (so it runs).

Example:

````
This runs but doesn't display the actual code
```{r}
5 * 5 
```


This results in both the code and execution being displayed
```
5 * 5
```
```{r}
5 * 5 
```
````

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[David Fong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574550/david-fong) provided a perfect solution for this in their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657730/9727624

To override the state, use `{r class.source = "fold-hide"}` if the yaml setting is `show`, and `{r class.source = "fold-show"}` if the setting is `hide`.