# Temporarely hiding code block with knitr markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using Markdown through RStudio and knitr to built a R exercises sheet for a course I'll give soon.  I want to hide the answer of the exercises like we can do here on stackoverflow.  example:

> This text his hidden

To see the box before, you have to put your cursor over it.  This is easily done here (on stackoverflow) by adding `>!` before what your want to hide.

How to I hide text like that in RMarkdown using knitr in RStudio?  I would like to hide the entire code block (the script and the result)

### Example of what I want to produce with knitr:

Question 1)

Evaluate the mean of this vector:

```
vec1 <- 1:5
```

Answer:

> `mean(vec1)`
>  `## 3`

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents) helps

Comment: Thanks @akrun, It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the trick.  It may even be better considering it forces people to click on the box, preventing accidental look.