# How to use code folding in Distill for R Markdown articles?

Tags: r-markdown

We have code folding in RMarkdown documents, but only when the output is `html_document`. The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839683/5359328 doesn't work in Distill for R Markdown Articles since the way of adding CSS and JS is unknown. How to use code folding in Distill for R Markdown Articles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [codefolder](https://github.com/ijlyttle/codefolder) package for either `Distill` documents or `Bookdown`.

For `Distill` this is done by including the following in the Rmarkdown document:

````
<aside>
```{r codefolder, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
codefolder::distill(init = "hide")
```
</aside>
````