# Adding button next to code in RMarkdown to hide/show code

Tags: r, r-markdown, kaggle

I have created an Rmarkdown file in a Kaggle Kernel and I am trying to do the following:

1) Set some code chunks as hidden but with a button next to them to allow the viewer to hide or display the code

2) Set some other codes chunks as not hidden with again a buttopn next to them to allow the viewer to hide or display the code

From what I could see in previous questions a suggested solution is

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---
```

That unfortunately is not working for me. I have also set the following in the start of my script

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo= TRUE)
````

and before each code I have the following:

````
```{r, message = FALSE, warning=FALSE  }
# Load packages
library("ggplot2")
library("pastecs")
library("dplyr")
library("corrplot")
````

So my question would be, what should I do to get 1) and 2)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `code_folding: hide` option should work. I'm not quite sure what a Kaggle Kernel is though, if the RMarkdown file displays on Kaggle's website they may not allow the javascript that's required to do the code folding?

Comment: @ Marius An example of a Kaggle Kernel is https://www.kaggle.com/hiteshp/head-start-for-data-scientist. Well I am using code_folding: hide but it is not working : )) That is why I thought that  maybe I am messing it with the other chunks of code

Comment: My kernel - you can see the code on the bottom is: https://www.kaggle.com/vamvas/replicating-disaster-on-the-titanic

Comment: Ah, just looked at your kernel and it looks like `code_folding` is not indented enough. It should be indented to the same level as `highlight` etc., it's a sub-option under `html_document`.

Comment: Thanks Marius, that worked like a charm

Comment: As a follow up is there a way to show specific chunks of code only? So set the option as above that will hide all code and then manually make certain code chunks to appear.

Comment: There are some related questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents, but I don't think there's a particularly easy way.