# generate html code from an r function to hide plots in markdown

Tags: html, r, quarto

I'm using quarto to generate an html report which contains a large number of plots. I don't want all of these plots to display, but I want the end-user to be able to display them if desired.

Quarto can have foldable code, but not foldable output, so I have found something like a workaround in html by saving the plot to a png, and using a collapsible button.

````
---
title: "untitled"
format: html
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
```

```{r}
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(13, 16, 33)
c <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
PLOT <- ggplot(c, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Title")
ggsave(plot = PLOT, file = paste("PLOT.png"))
```

```{=html}
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Expand me
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<div class="card card-body">
<img src="PLOT.png">
</div>
</div>
```
````

Ideally, I would be able to turn this into a function and either refer to the R plot object directly, or refer to the *.png. The following generates the right html code, but doesn't deploy it.

Would be very grateful if someone can help me to functionise this code, as I have hundreds of graphs, and copy-pasting all that html and renaming the buttons leaves a lot of room for error.

````
```{r}
f_hide_plot <- function(plot_output) {
  glue::glue('<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Expand me
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <img src="{plot_output}.png">
 </div>
</div>')
}

```

```{r}
glue::glue('{f_hide_plot(plot_output = "PLOT")}')
```
````

Comment: In case anyone else needs this I have found a workable solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents)

Scroll down to the "lo-fi" solution

`
<details><summary>Click text goes here</summary>
```{r}
PLOT
```
</details>
`