# How do I hide the code in all r notebook chunk?

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I have an r notebook, and I want all coding chunks to be hidden while their output is still displayed. I know I can add echo=F in the beginning of every chunk, but can I do it globally?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put this `opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)` in a code chunk at the document's head. Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091162/20002111

Comment: Also need to add require(knitr).